# How to extract words between certain character

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

Here's my datasets

```
      domainname
0     address=/000007.ru/0.0.0.0
1     address=/000007.ru/::
2     address=/000free.us/0.0.0.0
3     address=/000free.us/::
```

I want to extract word between `/` and `/` so the desired output is

```
      domainname                        website
0     address=/000007.ru/0.0.0.0        000007.ru
1     address=/000007.ru/::             000007.ru
2     address=/000free.us/0.0.0.0       000free.us
3     address=/000free.us/::            000free.us
```

Here's what I try

```
adsdata_vector = df["domainname"]
ads = []
for i in range(len(adsdata)):
   ads.append(re.split(r"[/]+",adsdata_vector[i]))
ads[0:4]
```

Here's what I get

```
[['address=', '000007.ru', '0.0.0.0'],
['address=', '000007.ru', '::'],
['address=', '000free.us', '0.0.0.0'],
['address=', '000free.us', '::']]
```

I only want second column only, please suggest something?

Comment: string split will help - you already have result - for a in ads a[1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If want extract first matched values use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df['website'] = df['domainname'].str.extract('/(.*?)/')
print (df)
                    domainname     website
0   address=/000007.ru/0.0.0.0   000007.ru
1        address=/000007.ru/::   000007.ru
2  address=/000free.us/0.0.0.0  000free.us
3       address=/000free.us/::  000free.us
```

Or if need all matched values use [`Series.str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) with [`Series.str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html):

```
df['website'] = df['domainname'].str.findall('/(.*?)/').str.join(', ')
```

If need ony second value after spliting by `/` use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with indexing:

```
df['website'] = df['domainname'].str.split('/').str[1]
```

Answer (score 3):

if the address is always `address=/000007.ru/0.0.0.0` and you want to extract the second column every time why not to use:

```
website = address.split('/')[1]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Series.str.extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df['website'] = df.domainname.str.extract(r'/(.+)/')

      domainname                        website
0     address=/000007.ru/0.0.0.0        000007.ru
1     address=/000007.ru/::             000007.ru
2     address=/000free.us/0.0.0.0       000free.us
3     address=/000free.us/::            000free.us
```

The regex `r'/(.+)/'` will find any character repeated one or more times between two `/`

Answer (score 2):

```
def f(y):    
  return [ x[1] for x in y ]
```